# Simple ObservableCollection binding ? Can't wrap my brain around it

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I want to bind a listbox to a simple observablecollection

XAML - Binding Listbox to my Observablecollection object

```
<Window x:Class="ObservableCollection.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ObservableCollection"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="Listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path= Test,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Adding a few items and trying to display the data in the listbox

```
namespace ObservableCollection
{
    /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ObservableCollection<int> Test = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        Listbox1.DataContext = Test;
        Test.Add(1);
        Test.Add(123232);
    }
}
}
```

The data doesnt show up when running the code.  What am I doing wrong here?
Thank you

Comment: `{Binding Path=.}` or `{Binding}`

Comment: Whats the difference between the two?  Why would I just leave it  = to Binding ?  Dont I have to link it to the path of my object that holds the data.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A binding expression will either include a property path, in which case the path must refer to a public property that exists on the `DataContext` object, or it will omit the path, in which case the binding will be to the `DataContext` object yourself.

In your example, you appear to be confusing the two. You configure the binding as if you want to omit the property path, but then in the XAML you provide a property path.

You can do one of the following…

Add a property to your `MainWindow` class and keep the path you have in the XAML:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<int> Test { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Test = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Test.Add(1);
        Test.Add(123232);
    }
}
```

Or, you can change your XAML to use the `DataContext` object directly:

```
<Window x:Class="ObservableCollection.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ObservableCollection"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="Listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Note that you also don't need to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property. The target value isn't ever going to change, so there's no reason to worry about how the source might be updated in such an event.

Comment: Thank you, when you set ItemSource ={"Binding}" , how does it know what to bind too.  Thats where im getting confused

Comment: ahh i get it.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;

    ObservableCollection<int> test = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    test.Add(1);
    test.Add(123232);
    Test = test;
}

public ObservableCollection<int> Test { get; set; }
```

Hopefully this clears things up. Your datacontext is where the IBindable consumers look.

Comment: Can you explain what you did here?  Why do I need to create Test outside of the MainWindow?  Thank you

Comment: @user3363744 Sorry was interrupted as I was typing out a good explaination for you. It looks like Peter has given you a nice summary of it. I recommend you look into the MVVM pattern at some point when you better understand XAML markdown and C#, it's how most enterprise level WPF applications are structured. Cheers!